# comparing some pattern with regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am parsing binary file. File size can be large. I want to search a some pattern in that file. the string is

> anynumber **0 obj<<** any
>   alpha,symbol,digit...anything
>   **>>endobj**

Bold text indicates compulsory string.
So, My QUESTION is - should I do it by regular expression or search it by coding. After that I want to store it in a dictionary.
If regular expression then what it be? what is the fastest way?
I am using VS-2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d+0 obj\<\<.*\>\>endobj
```

```
\d    - decimal digit
+     - 1 or more
\<    - < should be treated as a literal
.     - any character
*     - 0 or more
>    - > should be treated as a literal
```

Comment: Not any character. A period does not match a new line character by default.